# ActionLink pass parameter to area/controller/action from main

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

i have an `Admin` area

> localhost/Project/Admin/Category/Add

i can access it from root page by:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add New Category", "Add", "Categorys", new { area = "Admin" }, null)
```

now i wana have link from root page :

> localhost/Project/home/index

to:

> localhost/Project/Admin/Category/Edit/10

but this one not working :(

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Category 10", "Edit", "Categorys", new { area = "Admin" }, htmlAttributes: new { id=10})
```

Comment: `new { id = 10}` is adding a html attribute. It needs to be `@Html.ActionLink( ...., new { area = "Admin", id = 10 }, null)`

Comment: thanks men .very nice